# Cannot ReplaceExisting file in Current.LocalFolder

Tags: c#, windows, windows-runtime

I have an image file I get from the picker. I save it as 'me.png' in:

```
Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder
```

If I perform the action again to try to overwrite the old file with a new one the app crashes with:

```
    An exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.
```

The code I'm using to overwrite the file is:

```
            await file.CopyAsync(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder, "me.png", Windows.Storage.NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```

Any idea why this is happening? It's crashing on that line of code second time round. If I change the collision option to GenerateUniqueName it works fine so it seems to be a problem overwriting the file.

Update:

Full code

```
    localSettings.Values["me_image_path"] = "Asssets/pinkBackground.png";
                 tile.BackgroundImage = localSettings.Values["me_image_path"];

var picker = new FileOpenPicker();
            picker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
            picker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
            picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
            picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
            picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");

            StorageFile file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();

            if (file == null) return;
            await file.CopyAsync(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder, "me.png", Windows.Storage.NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

            localSettings.Values["me_image_path"] = "ms-appdata:///local/me.png";
            tile.BackgroundImage = localSettings.Values["me_image_path"];
```

Comment: Perhaps you've still got the old file open?

Comment: That's what I thought. I'm displaying it on a GridViewItem so before I call CopySync I change the GridViewItem's image to something else.

Comment: are you really overwriting me.jpg or is this a system file ?

Comment: It's a file I get from the users picture library and copy to my local storage folder. I'm trying to overwrite the version I have saved locally.

Comment: @MicahArmantrout I added the full code if that helps

Comment: Can you show the code where the temporary file is added to and removed from the GridViewItem?

Comment: @HarryJohnston I've added the code run to set the image before and after.

Comment: Perhaps it's just a copy-and-paste issue, but the line of code that should be changing the GridViewItem's image to something else currently appears to just point it at the existing file again.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Sorry it was a copy/paste issue. I've added the line before that which changes the image.

Comment: Does the image successfully change?

Comment: @HarryJohnston I can set the image using the picker. Then the first time I try to change it (to overwrite the current image) it crashes. The image successfully changes to the 'pinkBackground.png' before trying the overwrite.